# load html or div, menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need advice because I am desperate yet. I made easy menu and I used a:hover to change color (red) . I also set class "active" to color was still red when I click on the link. For now everything is going well. But I would like to.. when I click on a link of menu so that was changed only one  (content page). I know how load page or div in link, but I need to keep red color around link, when it is active specific link . I tried lots of solutions, but without success. If somebody helps me I will very grateful.
[link jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rh5n1emp/1/)

**HTML:**

```
 <div id="menu">
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a class="active" href="index.html"><b>POČÍTAČE</b></a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="kontaktys.html"><b>TVORBA W</b></a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#"><b>TISKOVINY</b></a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#"><b>SLUŽBY</b></a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#"><b>KONTAKTY</b></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
nav ul ul {
    display: none;
}
nav ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
nav ul {
    background: rgb(1, 1, 1);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    padding: 0 20px;
    border-radius: 0px;
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-table;
    font-family: Times New Roman;
    font-size: 70%;
}
nav ul:after {
    content:"";
    clear: both;
    display: block;
}
nav ul li {
    float: left;
}
nav ul li {
    float: left;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 1;
}
nav ul li a:hover, nav ul li a.active, nav ul li a.visited {
    background: rgb(177, 2, 10);
}
nav ul li:hover a {
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
nav ul li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 5px 45px;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    text-decoration: none;
    position: relative;
}
#menu {
    position: relative;
    width: 780px;
    height: 35px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -388px;
    overflow: hidden;
    top: -20px;
}
```

Comment: can you open a jsfiddler? and can you show your jquery?

Comment: first of all, ID's have to be unique. Never set the same ID to multiple elements, even in different contexts.

Comment: For now the code is updated.

Comment: I don't have jquery in this moment because I don't know how make this problem :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make this:

```
#lol a:hover, #lol a.active, #lol a.visited { 
    background: rgb(177,2,10);
}

#current, #lol a:hover, #lol a.active, #lol a.visited { 
    background: rgb(177,2,10);
}
```

Then on whichever page you are on, put the ID of `current` on the anchor element which links to that page.

So if you were on this page:

```
<li><a href="kontaktys.html"><b>TVORBA W</b></a>
```

You'd want it to be

```
<li><a  href="kontaktys.html" id="current"><b>TVORBA W</b></a>
```

Comment: I dont know how exactly you mean this. I added #current in css. I have div which to be changed (div id="content"). Where do I put id="current"? But thanks for answer and an effort to help.

Comment: Yes I understand you. If I set load() after click TVORBA W (for example) and in the load page will not again div id="menu" so this doesn't work, right?  Please check my jsfiddle. Thank you.

Comment: @RadekFojtík I'm not sure what your problem is, but this answer is probably correct. If you're using multiple HTML file, just add id="current" in each one to the related link. Or do you use jQuery / JS to load content after click?

Comment: @RadekFojtík, here is your fiddle, updated and working based on my answer: http://jsfiddle.net/rh5n1emp/3/

Comment: Yes I probably need jQuery/JS to load html page after click. When I load "page1" into div (content page) so I need to this link for "page1" was red - until I click another link of menu. I dont know if you undestand me :(

Comment: @RadekFojtík, if there is JS involved, show how it's being used. From your original post, there was no indication of scripting. How you choose to switch out the pages will change how to best do this. If you don't know how to do it with scripting, then mark this as the solution to the original question, and ask a new one focusing on how to switch out pages.

Comment: David thanks for your time. I will try another way to explain. I have html page where is: <body> <div>  </div> </body>. Already here isnt <div id="menu">. And this html page I want load into div in main html after click. I need to link was red. I cant put #current because there isnt id="menu". Is it ever possible?

Comment: @RadekFojtík where is the data coming from? This would be much easier if you could make a relevant example for me to run.

Comment: it seems OP wants to use his page as a master page, and load content dynamically into a container div. in this case ajax needs to be utilized.

Comment: @Banana, I figured that much, but is this data coming from a DB, from a file, from where? Are we changing everything, or parts? As I mentioned before, how he's loading will depend how the question is answered.

Comment: Thanks to everyone. I made other question with probably better description. [Link is here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26820273/how-to-switch-out-pages-load-into-div-menu)

Answer (score 0):

```
a:link {
    color: #FF0000;
}
```

or

```
a:link { }
```

Comment: You don't understand my question.:( You look on the jsfiddle.